# Openpyxl change the dimension of a chart

Tags: python-2.7, openpyxl

In openpyxl 2.2 I was able to set the dimension of a chart by using the drawing methods of the chart object:

```
chart = openpyxl.charts.BarChart()
chart.drawing.top = 100
chart.drawing.left = 100
chart.drawing.width = 600
chart.drawing.height = 600
```

In the new versions (>2.3.3), this method seems to not exist any more.
I read the online manual and I find as follows:

**"The chart can be positioned within its container. x and y adjust position, w and h adjust the size . The units are proportions of the container. A chart cannot be positioned outside of its container and the width and height are the dominant constraints: if x + w > 1, then x = 1 - w."**

So I thought that I had to change the container first. I searched in the manual for the class `openpyxl.chart.chartspace.ChartContainer` but I was not able to find a method to set its width and height.

How can I display a chart with fixed custom dimensions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The code for charts was completely rewritten in openpyxl 2.3. You can now set the approximate width and height in cm directly on your chart:

```
chart = openpyxl.chart.BarChart()
chart.height = 10 # default is 7.5
chart.width = 20 # default is 15
```

All chart measurements internally rely upon conversion to the operating system and can, thus, vary significantly between systems.

Comment: Thank you! Did I miss some part of the online manual or this kind of information is "hidden", so to speak, in a different chapter?

Comment: I think it may be in one of the examples or I may only have mentioned it on the mailing list. The API for creating and adding charts to sheets is somewhat experimental because of the different kinds of anchors (which actually determine the size) that are possible and I wanted to see what people preferred. Excel defaults to pinning corners of the chart to different cells but absolute positioning is also possible. :-/

Will add a note to the docs about the default settings as they seem to work for most people.

Comment: Great! I think Openpyxl is a a great piece of software and I'm eager to lern it more!

Comment: @CharlieClark is there a way to add transparency to an openpyxl chart? I’ve posted a question on this (my latest post) could you add suggestions? Thank you